# pdf viewer library for android

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked several times but I couldnt find one satisfying answer.My requirement is simple.just to open the pdf docs within my app(android).But I am not able to find a simple way of doing this.either its native c/c++ way or writing your own engine.But isnt there any simple API so that I can include it like a jar and view the pdf?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDF parsing library for Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android)

Comment: Take a look [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android/4766335#4766335). I think the most voted answer is really complete.
You will find both open source, most of them GPL3, and commercial solutions that should satisfy your needs.

Comment: Please see below StackOverflow link's answer for Read Pdf from sdcard. [Read PDF using PDFViewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152956/example-of-code-to-implement-a-pdf-reader/11153601#11153601)

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no API in the Android SDK to natively display PDF.

Solutions I can suggest:

-Use an external application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

-If your PDF document is accessible online, use the [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer) to open your PDF in a `WebView`:

```
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://mypdf.pdf
```

Comment: I analysed the above two solutions as well.The problem is the device may or ay not have reader installed and also my pdf is in internal storage:(.I know this has been asked over and over,but commercial one is also fine for me.I tried some,which was reaally really slow.

Answer (score 1):

you can use native plugin to show the PDF within your app. [try this apv](http://code.google.com/p/apv/)