# Example of code to implement a PDF reader

Tags: android, pdf

I want to implement a PDF reader in the application that I am doing, I have found several APIs, but none of them were open source.

Does any of you guys know a good free alternative?

---

### Slight adaptation of [Dipak Keshariya's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11153601/505893) made by the OP

**First Class**

```
package android.pdf.reader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

import net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class First extends Activity {
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File[] imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
        {  
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name)  
                {  
                        return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
                }  
        }); 
        String[] pdflist = new String[imagelist.length]; 
        for(int i = 0;i<imagelist.length;i++)
        {
                pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
        }
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            Object[] imagelist;
            String path = ((File) imagelist[(int)id]).getAbsolutePath();
            openPdfIntent(path);
    }

    private void openPdfIntent(String path) 
    {
        try
        {
          final Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
          intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
          startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Second Class**

```
package android.pdf.reader;

import net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Second extends PdfViewerActivity 
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.left_arrow;
}

public int getNextPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.right_arrow;
}

public int getZoomInImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.zoom_in;
}

public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.zoom_out;
}

public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
    return R.layout.pdf_file_password;
}

public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
    return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber;
}

public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
    return R.id.etPassword;
}

public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
    return R.id.btOK;
}

public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
    return R.id.btExit;
}

public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
    return R.id.pagenum_edit;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you know about PDFViewer library to read PDF files?

Comment: I do not know anything about what you speak

Comment: Hi i just wanted to ask where can I get the PdfViewerActivity ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use below code for that.

First.java

```
public class First extends ListActivity {

    String[] pdflist;
    File[] imagelist;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
            }
        });
        pdflist = new String[imagelist.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < imagelist.length; i++) {
            pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
        }
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String path = imagelist[(int) id].getAbsolutePath();
        openPdfIntent(path);
    }

    private void openPdfIntent(String path) {
        try {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
            intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Second.java

```
public class Second extends PdfViewerActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.left_arrow;
    }

    public int getNextPageImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.right_arrow;
    }

    public int getZoomInImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.zoom_in;
    }

    public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.zoom_out;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.pdf_file_password;
    }

    public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
        return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
        return R.id.etPassword;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
        return R.id.btOK;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
        return R.id.btExit;
    }

    public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
        return R.id.pagenum_edit;
    }
}
```

And declared both activities into your manifest file.

Comment: I'm trying it, the entire project, but does not work                           https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library/zipball/master

Comment: don't use this, only use above link's answer because it is useful in my case and if u have any query then tell me i will give you source code of that and the above link is for read the pdf file from sdcard.

Comment: First thank you for answering so quickly. Do I think you say to look at the code which put # SPK? But it is incomplete, missing the main activity declares, etc...

Comment: In Above link, the First.java is main launcher activity and another one is default activity file

Comment: final Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
      intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
      startActivity(intent);
But here i see PdfViewerActivity.class, first.class and Second.class?

Comment: Are you add the PDFViewer.jar file in your java build path?

Comment: yes, but for example the method "setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>)" is undefined :S

Comment: are you writing this line into click event or onCreate method?

Comment: Yes, i put in the post my 2 class

Comment: i don't understand your last comment, please give some more information.

Comment: I have edited the main post, so you can see the status of my project. I'm sorry if I explained bad or my English doesn't make much sense

Comment: Please see my edited answer and your code is perfect but in your main activity you are extends activity instead of listactivity.

Comment: Thank you, now I have no errors! Can I read pdf's resources or also from a url?

Comment: using above code you are read pdf from sdcard only, it is possible to change some code and read pdf from resources and url also but i don't know.

Comment: I'll have to find a way to read pdf's from a url. Finally you was very patient with me and I gave a great help, thanks!

Comment: This library is extremely slow for me - do you have this problem. I am not able to even open a pdf file - it shows pdf loading for a long time

Comment: @DipakKeshariya is it possible to set page to view before it loads the PDF File to screen?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya can you provide me pdfreading code on jolapara.pankaj@gmail.com i reqiured it if possible then pls mail me.
Thanks

Comment: @DipakKeshariya to display pdf our PDF file should be in Sd card ? or we can display from assets folder? .. in my case logcat show me
that 03-06 11:02:10.695: I/PDFVIEWER(5712): ST='file 'file:///android_asset/publicatios/rapportActivite.pdf' not found'

Comment: @DipakKeshariya It display RestoreInstance in Red line.. i think problem there.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya is it possible to set pinch to zoom functionality?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya only include of jar file an error shown at PdfViewerActivity

Comment: @Swap-IOS-Android If you are testing this code using emulator and reading the file from sdcard, then simply push the pdf file into the mnt/sdcard folder in the file explorer and run the app again, it will start working.

Comment: this is working fine,but it doesn't provide pinch zoom facility.Can we archive pinch zoom ficility for this example(pdf viewer)

Comment: Hi dipak, i implimented this,but my problem is how to impliment pinch zoom facility for this?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya from where we can get `PDFViewer.jar` ?

Comment: How can we extract text from that PDF file?

Answer (score 3):

[There is a very good post about this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android). In particular check out the answer given by Commons.Ware, it answers your question.

Following your comments I have added the links here from the SO post I mentioned above (source for projects you could not find):

- [Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library (hosted at Github)](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library.)
- [APV (hosted at Google code, uses Mercurial)](http://code.google.com/p/apv/source/checkout)
- [Android PDF Viewer (hosted at Sourceforge, uses SVN)](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=265752)

So "checkout" or clone the repositories to your local file system to browse the code.
As I mentioned in my  comment check the licence of each library before you go any further to see if what you can and cannot do with the code.

Comment: Thanks for response, But these links only see to download apk's. I need the code

Comment: read that post I can see atleast 2 if not 3 links to projects hosted on google code and the source being available.

Comment: http://www.dataviz.com/products/documentstogo/android/
http://www.cerience.com/products/reader/android
http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/
http://code.google.com/p/apv/
These are all the links that I found, but I don't see any code to download on these websites

Comment: try the source tab on the ones hosted on google code. You can clone the repository to your machine. Check the licence to see what limitations are there for use of the library.  so for apv (hosted at google code) you need to use Mercurial. For AndPdf hosted at sourceforge it is using SVN. again try reading through the project pages.

Comment: There's no answer by Commons.Ware.. please refer to it with a link to the answer.

Comment: Is there any method by which this can be integrated inside our project it self without using any third part project?

Answer (score 3):

This one works for me.

1) Add PdfViewer.jar into your project’s build path

2) Copy the following drawable resources from PdfViewer/res/drawable into YourProject/res/drawable left_arrow.png right_arrow.png zoom_in.png zoom_out.png

3) Copy the following layout resources from PdfViewer/res/layout into YourProject/res/layout dialog_pagenumber.xml pdf_file_password.xml

4) Derive your PDF activity from net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity

5) Using the default drawables and layouts:

```
public int getPreviousPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.left_arrow; }

public int getNextPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.right_arrow; }

public int getZoomInImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_in; }

public int getZoomOutImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_out; }

public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() { return R.layout.pdf_file_password; }

public int getPdfPageNumberResource() { return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber; }

public int getPdfPasswordEditField() { return R.id.etPassword; }

public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() { return R.id.btOK; }

public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() { return R.id.btExit; }

public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() { return R.id.pagenum_edit; }
enter code here
```

6) Invoke your PdfViewActivity derived with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourPdfViewerActivity.class);

intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, "PATH TO PDF GOES HERE");

startActivity(intent);
```

And you can download the source code from this link. [LINK](https://app.box.com/shared/0639432f84e000f6f04f)

Hope this helps :)