# error in opening pdf file in android,

Tags: java, android, html, pdf

My project in android use html file to navigate pages, and there is a link that will open a pdf file.

here is the html code for the html :

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.jsinterface.pdf1Click();" style="font-size: 0.9em; padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px; font-family:serif; color:white; text-decoration: none;">My PDF</a>
```

and this is the code for in my src.

```
public void pdf1Click() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                        ReadWriteDisplayPDFFile(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pdf1),"pdf1.pdf");
                        }
                    });
                }
```

but when I run my project and click to the link to open the pdf file,
it can't open the pdf file and i got this error:

```
Error Writting on /sdcard/myproj/pdf1.pdf
Please Inserd SD Card
```

and

```
No Application available to view pdf
```

does anyone have an Idea about my case?
thanks in advance

logcat:

```
Error writing /sdcard/myproj/pdf1.pdf 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/myproj/pdf1.pdf : open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
    at com.sample.AppActivity$JSInterface.ReadWriteDisplayPDFFile(AppActivity.java:146)

    START {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///sdcard/myproj/pdf1.pdf typ=application/pdf flg=0x4000000 u=0} from pid 626
```

Comment: Did you test it on an Emulator?

Comment: Yes, I am currently in the Emulator

Comment: Did you configure it to have a SD card And please post the whole LogCat with the related method(s).

Comment: iTuki, I have now configured my SD card but I got the problem `No Application available to view pdf`

Comment: May be there is no PDF app reader installed in your emulator. You need to install any PDF Reader App. Try [this one](http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below Stack overflow's answer for read pdf using pdfviewer library, it may help you and if you have any query regarding that then tell me.

[Example of code to implement a PDF reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152956/example-of-code-to-implement-a-pdf-reader/11153601#11153601)