# Open PDF in android application without using library & installed reader in Android

Tags: android

I need to open PDF for reading,rendering & annotation in my own application W/o using any third party tool or library like MuPDF & APV Viewer,in webview etc.

Is there any way to open PDF in my app in android without using above.

Please help me !!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to read pdf without any library, you can use PDFViewer.jar library to read pdf into your application, use below SO link's answer for read PDF using PDFViewer.jar

[Read PDF using PDFViewer.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152956/example-of-code-to-implement-a-pdf-reader/11153601#11153601)

Download Jar file from below link.

http://www.filecrop.com/pdf-viewer.jar.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply !!!!

I want to add annotation on PDF like highlight,search text etc in my app.
PDFViewer convert PDF into images so how can I achieve this target using this lib ??

Answer (score 0):

refer qtuestion

[Render a PDF file using Java on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456344/display-pdf-within-app-on-android)

it will show you the best methods available to open a pdf in android i dont think there is a way to open without using either of these things mentioned above

```
  public class MyPdfViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
WebView mWebView=new WebView(MyPdfViewActivity.this);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+LinkTo);
setContentView(mWebView);
 }
 }
```

best method to open without an api or installed prog

Comment: "LinkTo" is the path of file in sdcard?

Comment: Thanks for your reply !!!!

webview does not allow to add annotation in PDF,so how can i achieve this ??

Comment: try using itext library for tha

Comment: In fact, that's not a good solution because 1. What if Google decides to change their address? and 2. After sending several requests, you will get an error saying that you have exceeded the limit of pdf views outside of Google Drive

Answer (score 0):

Posting this if it could help someone some day, In order to view pdf files in android you can make use of the [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) which requires you to add the web related files in assets folder which includes the js files in the index.html and call the index.html by passing the url of the pdf file as query parameter and load it in the webview.

Pros:
User need not navigate away from the webview
You can reuse the same to display PDFs which are hosted in server or available withing the application also you can view pdf which require to login using cookies.
Cons:
There will be a slight increase in app size.