# How to open any pdf file inside app?

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-reader

I'm new in android development so I know how to open pdf from assest folder file by using some of the available API .

But how can I make for any pdf means like adobe reader.

Comment: alone you cant dear..(:

Comment: by the way this might be help full to u http://stackoverflow.com/a/13344414/1199602

Comment: You can use third party libraries. Here I have given that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583095/pdf-viewer-api-on-android/14583151#14583151

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to open Adobe Reader (with a version) specifically from your app, you need to query it using [`PackageManager.getPackageInfo(String, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)!

You can also try the following code,

```
private void loadDocInAdobeReader(String someDoc)
     throws ActivityNotFoundException, Exception {

    try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(someDoc), "application/pdf");
                startActivity(intent);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ae) {
                ae.printStackTrace();
                throw ae;
    } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                throw e;
    }
}
```