# Open PDF shows error like screen

Tags: android, pdf, android-emulator

I am trying to open an pdf document which resides in res/raw folder.when clicking on the button it shows the screen as follows [image: image link].

I am not sure why is this showing like this...

Please let me know and thanks ...

Please find my code as below

```
    Button MyRawBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonId2);
            MyRawBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "ImageButton (selector) is clicked!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    File pdfFile = new File("res/raw/sample.pdf");
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 

                    //Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.sample);
                    //File file = new File(uri.toString());

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(path,"application/pdf");
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                        startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Comment: Are you using PDFViewer.jar library?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya: i am using the AndroidPdfViewer_1_0_1.apk

Comment: Please see my answer and if it is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Use below Stack Overflow Answer's link code for Read PDF using PDFViewer.jar library into your android application and if you have any query regarding that then tell me.

[Code to Implement a PDF Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152956/example-of-code-to-implement-a-pdf-reader/11153601#11153601)