# open pdf in my layout without any viewer offline

Tags: android

I am creating school application and i want to open pdf in my layout i use pdfviewer but that class convert a pdf into a image and view in that class view.
is there any way to open a pdf inside my app without any viewer and i am not using any net connectivity so i am not able to use google doc to open my pdf .

So how can i open a pdf in my lay out i show this example [Example of code to implement a PDF reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152956/example-of-code-to-implement-a-pdf-reader/11153601#11153601) but this is show in pdfviewer class layout not in my layout.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/doc/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android)?

You can embed a MuPDFReaderView in your layout. Here a pseudo code; in your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* First create the document view */
    mDocView = new MuPDFReaderView(this) {
        @Override
        protected void onMoveToChild(int i) {
            super.onMoveToChild(i);
            Log.d("MyTAG", "pages: " + 
                String.format("%d / %d", i + 1, core.countPages()));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onTapMainDocArea() {
            Log.d("MyTAG", "onTapMainDocArea");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDocMotion() {
            Log.d("MyTAG", "onDocMotion");
        }
    };

    /* Set the rendering mode */
    mDocView.setMode(MuPDFReaderView.Mode.Drawing);

    /* Load the PDF document... */
    core = new MuPDFCore(path_to_your_pdf_file);
    /* ...and connect the core at the view */
    mDocView.setAdapter(new MuPDFPageAdapter(this, core));

    /* Add the MuPDFReaderView to this layout */
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.addView(mDocView);
    /* Add more views layout.addView(myOtherView); */
    setContentView(layout);

    /* TODO ...your other code... */        
}
```