# Online pdf viewer as Google docs

Tags: android, webview

Currently my app opens online PDF files in Webview with help from Google docs, my link to the URL looks like this:

```
webV.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=mylinkto.pdf");
```

And it works just fine. My question is there other PDF viewers except Google docs that works the same. So I can just combine link and open it in Webview?

Comment: check this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152956/example-of-code-to-implement-a-pdf-reader

Comment: Thanx, this is nice, but not what i asked.

Comment: hi, how does this work for you gives me an error, "sorry there is no proview available."

Comment: Google Docs often show different errors.