# How to read pdf with vertical scrolling using third party library.

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which I wanted to implement PDF view functionality with vertical scrolling, please guide any free third party library by which vertical scrolling can be implemented while viewing PDF.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: see [this][1] may be help to you in pdf view.......


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152956/example-of-code-to-implement-a-pdf-reader/11153601#11153601

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** First Add jar **PdfViewer.jar** from https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library to your **libs** folder and also right click it and in build path -> click on "add to build path"

**Step 2 :** Copy the following drawable folder to your **res** folder from PdfViewer/res/drawable into YourProject/res/drawable

The files to be copied are

1.> back01.png 
  2.> back02.png 
  3.> doc.png 
  4.> folder.png 
  5.> icon.png 
  6.> left_arrow.png 
  7.> pdf.png 
  8.> right_arrow.png 
  9.> zoom_in.png 
  10.> zoom_out.png

But make sure you copy the folder drawable in res folder.

**Step 3:** Copy the following layout resources to your **res>layout** folder from PdfViewer/res/layout into YourProject/res/layout

The files to be copied are

1.> dialog_pagenumber.xml 
 
  2.> graphics_view.xml 
  3.> navigation_overlay.xml 
  4.> pdf_file_password.xml 
  5.> scroll_layout.xml

**Step 4:** Derive your PDF activity from net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity as below

```
package com.example.viewsdcardpdfs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity;

public class mypdfactivity extends PdfViewerActivity{
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.left_arrow;
    }

    public int getNextPageImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.right_arrow;
    }

    public int getZoomInImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.zoom_in;
    }

    public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.zoom_out;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.pdf_file_password;
    }

    public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
        return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
        return R.id.etPassword;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
        return R.id.btOK;
    }

    public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
        return R.id.btExit;
    }

    public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
        return R.id.pagenum_edit;
    }
 }
```

**Step 5 :** In your **MainActivity** call as follow

```
package com.example.viewsdcardpdfs;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

import net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] pdflist;
File[] imagelist;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
        }
    });
    pdflist = new String[imagelist.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < imagelist.length; i++) {
        pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
    }
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
}

 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String path = imagelist[(int) id].getAbsolutePath();
        openPdfIntent(path);
    }

 private void openPdfIntent(String path) {
        try {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, mypdfactivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**Step 6:** In your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.viewsdcardpdfs"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.viewsdcardpdfs.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.viewsdcardpdfs.mypdfactivity">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**Step 7 :** Run your code

Comment: I am looking for vertical scrolling of PDF with out moving one by one of page scrolling.

Comment: Very late comment. But It might help someone.You can try this : enable swipeVertical for vertical scrolling. pdfView.fromAsset("sample.pdf").swipeVertical(true)

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following worked for me                     `.swipeVertical(true)` add the line as shown below

```
 pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
               // .pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3)
                .defaultPage(1)
                .showMinimap(false)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeVertical(true)
                //.onDraw(onDrawListener)
                .onLoad(this)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .load();
```