# PDFReader utility radaee causing application crashed

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am using following code in my PDFActivity but application is being crashed when I used it as

```
import com.radaee.util.PDFHttpStream;
import com.radaee.pdf.Document;
public class PdfActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        PDFHttpStream m_stream = new PDFHttpStream();
        Document m_doc = new Document();
        ReaderController m_vPDF = new ReaderController(this);
        m_doc.Close();
        m_stream.open("http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/maven.pdf");
        int ret = m_doc.OpenStream(m_stream, null);
        if( ret == 0 ) {
            m_vPDF.open(m_doc);
            setContentView( m_vPDF );
        }

}
}
```

logcat:

```
05-08 12:57:04.971 20892-20892/com.radaee.reader W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-08 12:57:06.551 20892-20892/com.radaee.reader E/art: No implementation found for long com.radaee.pdf.Document.openStream(com.radaee.pdf.Document$PDFStream, java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_radaee_pdf_Document_openStream and Java_com_radaee_pdf_Document_openStream__Lcom_radaee_pdf_Document_00024PDFStream_2Ljava_lang_String_2)
05-08 12:57:06.561 20892-20892/com.radaee.reader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.radaee.reader, PID: 20892
                                                                   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.radaee.pdf.Document.openStream(com.radaee.pdf.Document$PDFStream, java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_radaee_pdf_Document_openStream and Java_com_radaee_pdf_Document_openStream__Lcom_radaee_pdf_Document_00024PDFStream_2Ljava_lang_String_2)
                                                                       at com.radaee.pdf.Document.openStream(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.radaee.pdf.Document.OpenStream(Document.java:765)
                                                                       at com.radaee.reader.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:44)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2415)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:164)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

Comment: post logcat also...

Comment: 05-08 12:55:25.671 312-312/? E/PSD: set_ps_threshold: low_thd 183 high_thd 223  ps:103 crosstalk:63  state:1 
05-08 12:55:26.041 312-312/? E/PSD: set_ps_threshold: low_thd 185 `high_thd 225  ps:105 crosstalk:63  state:1 
05-08 12:55:26.411 312-312/? E/PSD: set_ps_threshold: low_thd 181 high_thd 221  ps:101 crosstalk:63  state:1 
05-08 12:55:26.771 312-312/? E/PSD: set_ps_threshold:`

Comment: just this? where is complete fatal error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native library is not loaded, you need to call `Global.Init( this );` first.

```
Global.Init( this );
PDFHttpStream m_stream = new PDFHttpStream();
Document m_doc = new Document();
ReaderController m_vPDF = new ReaderController(this);
m_stream.open("http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/maven.pdf");
int ret = m_doc.OpenStream(m_stream, null);
if( ret == 0 ) {
   m_vPDF.open(m_doc);
   setContentView( m_vPDF );
}
```

Comment: What to import for Global class?

Comment: com.radaee.pdf.Global